# Merging and expanding a column to a dataframe based on row names

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a variable, which level occur several times and a second dataframe containing a code for unique levels of this variable. I would like to add a column containing the codes to  my dataframe. This is best illustrated by an example:

```
f1 <- rep(c("A","B","C"), each = 3)
df1 <- data.frame(f1,v1=runif(9))

  f1         v1
1  A 0.83523506
2  A 0.13833162
3  A 0.15354252
4  B 0.62046499
5  B 0.27823892
6  B 0.04629973
7  C 0.85571269
8  C 0.10963561
9  C 0.70576556

df2 <- data.frame(f1=c("A","B","C"), n1=c("sp1","sp2","sp3") )

  f1  n1
 1  A sp1
 2  B sp2
 3  C sp3

df3 <- data.frame(f1=rep(c("A","B","C"),each = 3),n1=rep(c("sp1","sp2","sp3"),each =3),v1=df1$v1)

  f1  n1         v1
1  A sp1 0.83523506
2  A sp1 0.13833162
3  A sp1 0.15354252
4  B sp2 0.62046499
5  B sp2 0.27823892
6  B sp2 0.04629973
7  C sp3 0.85571269
8  C sp3 0.10963561
9  C sp3 0.70576556
```

I would like to find a function to obtain df3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways

using base function `merge` is simple

```
merge(df1,df2)
```

here's another one using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2)

#  f1        v1  n1
#1  A 0.2283936 sp1
#2  A 0.3709602 sp1
#3  A 0.2508059 sp1
#4  B 0.5654418 sp2
#5  B 0.3206994 sp2
#6  B 0.2529365 sp2
#7  C 0.7200121 sp3
#8  C 0.5247517 sp3
#9  C 0.1914874 sp3
```

My numbers vary from yours as you didn't use `set.seed` to set the random number generation

Comment: It seemed to work, but after examination of the results I noticed a number of NA values that appeared as a result of merging the df. May it be because the levels of the variable to merge are not in the same order? How to relevel adequately?

Comment: well, you'd need to produce a longer example.  It shouldn't matter what order your dfs are in because merge performs a sort as it works.    You could try     merge(df1,df2,by="f1")   to be super-specific about what variable you're merging.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to fix it. I will control the names of all my variables to be sure that there is no mismatch.